# Trim an account number in sql

Tags: sql-server

I kept searching in Google the exact words to use in order to trim the first 18 digits and a space from this account number. I'm using SQL Server 2012. Should I use the word `TRIM`?

```
 000000000000000000 111WH1566740
```

Comment: This link contains a listing of string functions that may be helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a lot on what your requirements are, exactly... is it always "18 characters plus one space" that you want to trim off? If so, a hard-coded solution like this will work for you:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('000000000000000000 111WH1566740', 
                 20, 
                 LEN('000000000000000000 111WH1566740') - 17)
```

If it's actually more like "Trim off everything to the left of the first space, including the space", then this will do that work:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('000000000000000000 111WH1566740', 
       CHARINDEX(' ', '000000000000000000 111WH1566740') + 1,
       LEN('000000000000000000 111WH1566740') - CHARINDEX(' ', '000000000000000000 111WH1566740') + 1)
```

Of course, that would look a lot nicer if the value were a column name rather than a literal string, but you get the gist of it.